# How to setup magento facebook login with facebook app create and configure step by step?

Tags: magento-1.9

All step complete but some problem?
app id = XXXXXXXXXXXXX and app secrate = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX setup but not working?

Comment: verify you provide proper website URL while creating facebook app. Verify not any space before or after URL specify.

Comment: No space wheen creating facebook app. Another solution?

Comment: Now when you try to it in website? What problem you are facing?

Comment: Redirect to facebook login page and facebook email and password then redirect to magento site customer email problem.

Comment: Have to dubug code, Which line of code in your controller give you error. Can you do that.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/UD6PuYQs

Comment: check that error report text in Magento Root -> var -> report folder.

Comment: can you share controller code, how you try to get customer email ?

Comment: protected function getCustomerByEmail($email, $website_id){
  $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
  if (Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/scope')) {
   $collection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',$website_id);
  }
  return $collection->getFirstItem();
 }

Comment: uesd to magestore extension- facebook-login-v1.7_magentoce1.5-1.9

Comment: did you share the code of that controller action? means all code. So I will give you idea where you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Magestore_Fblogin_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        if(!Mage::helper('magenotification')->checkLicenseKeyFrontController($this)){return;}
        $isAuth = $this->getRequest()->getParam('auth');
        $facebook = Mage::helper('fblogin')->createFacebook();
        $userId = $facebook->getUser();

        if($isAuth && !$userId && $this->getRequest()->getParam('error_reason') == 'user_denied'){
                echo("<script>window.close()</script>");
        }elseif ($isAuth && !$userId){
                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
                exit;
        }
        $user = Mage::helper('fblogin')->getFbUser();
        if ($isAuth && $user){
        $nextUrl = Mage::helper('fblogin')->getFbloginUrl();
        if($nextUrl!='')
            die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location.href=\"".$nextUrl."\"; window.close();</script>");
        else
            die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location.href=window.opener.location.href;</script>");
        }
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); //add them
        $website_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();//add them
        $data =  array('firstname'=>$user['first_name'], 'lastname'=>$user['last_name'], 'email'=>$user['email']);
        $customer = $this->getCustomerByEmail($data['email'], $website_id); //edit
        if(!$customer || !$customer->getId()){
            $customer = $this->createCustomerMultiWebsite($data, $website_id, $store_id);   //add them      
        }
        //add old
        if ($customer->getConfirmation()){
            try {
                $customer->setConfirmation(null);
                $customer->save();
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('fblogin')->__('Error'));
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $this->_redirectUrl($this->_loginPostRedirect());//add them fix new
    }

    protected function getCustomerByEmail($email, $website_id){
        $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/scope')) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',$website_id);
        }
        return $collection->getFirstItem();
    }

    protected function createCustomer($data){
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($data['email']);

        $isSendPassToCustomer = Mage::getStoreConfig('fblogin/general/is_send_password_to_customer');
        $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword();
        $customer->setPassword($newPassword);
        try{
            $customer->save();
        }catch(Exception $e){}

        if($isSendPassToCustomer)
            $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
        return $customer;
    }
    // add them 
    protected function createCustomerMultiWebsite($data, $website_id, $store_id){
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        $customer ->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($data['email'])
                    ->setWebsiteId($website_id)
                    ->setStoreId($store_id)
                    ->save()
                    ;
        $isSendPassToCustomer = Mage::getStoreConfig('fblogin/general/is_send_password_to_customer');
        $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword();
        $customer->setPassword($newPassword);
        try{
            $customer->save();
        }catch(Exception $e){}

        if($isSendPassToCustomer)
            $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
        return $customer;
    }
    //add old
        protected function _loginPostRedirect(){
            $selecturl= Mage::getStoreConfig(('fblogin/general/select_url'),Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            if($selecturl==0) return Mage::getUrl('customer/account');
            if($selecturl==2) return Mage::getUrl();
            if($selecturl==3) return Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFbCurrentpage();
            if($selecturl==4) return Mage::getStoreConfig(('fblogin/general/custom_page'),Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            if($selecturl==1 && Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount()!=0) return Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');else return Mage::getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your solution? Or is this your current code?

Comment: Current code. Problem https://www.screencast.com/t/UD6PuYQs

Comment: In that case, could you update your original post with the code snippet? It will make things easier to read. Thanks